# I am having trouble compiling and running my C program. What are the commands?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, compiler-options

I am having trouble compiling and running my C program. What are the commands?

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

I tried compiling with

```
gcc -o hello.c
```

only to be unsuccessful. I am using a Mac terminal, if that matters.

Comment: and which command gave you trouble?

Comment: Also, it is preferable to use `return` instead of `exit`(which also needs `stdlib.h`) in `main` or remove it altogether as it is implicit in the case of `main`.

Comment: I tried `gcc -o hello.c`

Comment: Wrong command. Use `gcc hello.c -o hello -Wall -Wextra -std=c11` and then open `hello.exe`. (The first two words compiles `hello.c`, `-o hello` names the .exe to `hello.exe`, `-Wall -Wextra` enables several warnings and `-std=c11` compiles the program with the latest (as of now) C standard)

Comment: What does this question have to do with emacs?

Comment: Removed the Emacs details, since they appear completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

In `gcc`, option `-o` is used to specify a custom output filename. The *immediate* next argument should be the file name.

> `-o file`
>
> Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

A simple revised command will be

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

where, `hello` is the name of the binary.

You can check the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) for more info.